# Docker on Ubuntu has no access to imternet

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I try to build my container I get the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package wget
E: Unable to locate package unzip
E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package default-jdk
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install wget unzip git default-jdk -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Here's a list of commands which are supposed to be executed:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget unzip git default-jdk -y
```

From my limited understanding of linux and docker, it's clear that docker has no access to internet.

Docker version:

- Server Version: 20.10.2
- Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3
- Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker

Ubuntu: 16.04LTS

Things I tried:

- added to `/etc/default/docker` this line `DOCKER_OPTS="--ip-masq=true --dns MY_DNS1 --dns MY_DNS2"`
- commeted out `#dns=dnsmasq` from `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Do you use docker in conjunction with docker-compose or standalone? In case of the former, explicit network settings matter. In case of the latter, try fetching some official image (in case you didnt already) that connects to the internet and see if that works.
Also tell us how you run the docker container. I'm assuming the Ubuntu host does have access to the internet?

Comment: @lordZ3d what's your base image? (`FROM <base_image>`)

Answer (score 0):

If this is not your image, then port 80:80 may not be enabled, if you have the Dockerfile, then you would be able to find out the answer. If this is your Dockerfile, then you would need to add port 80:80 unless you want to use a different port in your container to bind to port 80 on the host.